# Typescript + create-react-app: Interfacing with existing Javascript libraries?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I have an existing JavaScript library that expects to be called like this:

```
Area.Subcategory.fn();
```

I'm trying to call this from a typescript app I created with **create-react-app**. However, I'm not able to create a type declaration file that is actually used.

I've created a type declaration file, `test.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace Area.Subcategory {
    function fn(): void;
}
```

Then, I've instructed `App.tsx` to use this type declaration:

```
///<reference path="./test.d.ts" />
import React from "react";
export interface IAppProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, any> {
    public componentDidMount() {
        Area.Subcategory.fn();
    }
    public render() {
        return <div className="App">(placeholder)</div>;
    }
}
```

I also tried wrapping the declaration in a module, although I was suspicious since that changes the calling pattern:

test.d.ts:

```
declare module "test" {
    export namespace Area.Subcategory {
        function fn(): void;
    }
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import * as test from "test";
...
    public componentDidMount() {
        test.Area.Subcategory.fn();
    }
```

Additionally, I've tried moving the original test.d.ts file up to a higher "typings" directory and referencing that in tsconfig.json. That did not impact the results.

With just the /// directive, I got:

```
'Area' is not defined  no-undef
```

When I tried putting it in a module, I got:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'test' in (path)
```

The first attempt seemed more promising, but it seems the Typescript compiler is ignoring the type declaration file. As a test, I tried putting a blatant syntax error in test.d.ts - and the output didn't mention it.

How am I supposed to declare this function?

Comment: How do you add this library to the resulting code? Is it attached in a separate `<script>` tag?

Comment: Yep, for testing purposes I just added a <script> tag to public/index.html